# Exception to definition of a function.

Tags: functions

My book gives me this definition of a function:

- A function $f$ is a special kind of relation,i.e $f\subset A\times
     B$,such that the following hold:
- for each $a\in A$ there exist $b    \in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$
- No two ordered pairs in $f$ has the    same first element.

Now, consider $f:A\to B$ such that $f(x) = x^2$. Let $Dom(f) = R$ and $Range(f)= R$. Now :
For $x=2$, we have $f(x) = 4$.
For $x=-2$ , we have $f(x) = 4$

Clearly, the above results are satisfying the definition of a function.

Now, let $r:A\to B$ such that $r(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Let $Dom(r) = R$ and $Range(r) = R$.
Now here, for $x=4$ , we have $r(x) = 2$ or $r(x) = -2$
The above result is satisfying the second bullet point, but it is not satisfying the third bullet point. What is the mistake that I am doing here?

Link to a similar question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490047/definition-of-a-function). But quite honestly, I dont think the answers on this link are promising for me atleast.

Comment: The domain of $r$ is not $\mathbb R$ but is $[0,\infty)$. Secondly $\sqrt4=2$ and $\sqrt4\neq-2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the second bullet point, unless one restricts the domain to $[0,\infty)$, say.
However, it is not correct (under the generally used *definition* of square root) that $r(4)=-2$. For non-negative $x$, we *define* $\sqrt x$ to be the unique non-negative real number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. We do *not* define $\sqrt x$ as "just any" number $y$ such that $y^2=x$.